# Room database test fails when I call another operation within same coroutine context

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, android-room, android-testing

I have a repository that has a DAO. I use this repo to store a coin object inside Room database.

My repo is the following:

```
class CoinPickerRepoImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val coinDao: CoinDao,
    @IoDispatcher private val coroutineDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
): CoinPickerRepository {
  
 override suspend fun updateSelectedCoin(id: String) {
        withContext(coroutineDispatcher) {
            coinDao.unselectAllCoins()
            coinDao.selectCoin(id)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my two DAO methods are like this:

```
@Dao
interface CoinDao {

 @Query("UPDATE coinentity SET selected = 0")
    suspend fun unselectAllCoins()

    @Query("UPDATE coinentity SET selected = 1 WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun selectCoin(id: String)
}
```

Now, this is working fine within the app, but, when doing unit tests for this specific operation I always get an assertion error (it retrieves a null object, and is telling me that it cannot reach anything inside the database):

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@SmallTest
class CoinPickerRepoImplTest {

    private lateinit var coinDao: CoinDao
    private lateinit var coinpickerRepository: CoinPickerRepository
    private lateinit var db: AppDatabase

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    private val testDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Before
    fun setup() {
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase::class.java
        ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        coinDao = db.coinDao()
        coinpickerRepository =
            CoinPickerRepoImpl(coinDao = coinDao, coroutineDispatcher = testDispatcher)
        runBlocking {
            initDb(coinDao)
        }
    }

    @After
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun closeDb() {
        db.close()
    }

    @Test
    fun update_selected_coin_test() = runTest {
        coinpickerRepository.updateSelectedCoin("BTC")
        val selectedCoinId = coinpickerRepository.getSelectedCoinId()
        assertNotNull(selectedCoinId)
        assertEquals(selectedCoinId, coinDao.getSelectedCoin()?.id)
        assertTrue(coinDao.selectedCoinExists())
    }
}

private suspend fun initDb(coinDao: CoinDao) {
    coinDao.insertAll(cryptoCoins.map { cryptoCoin ->
        CoinEntity(
            id = cryptoCoin.id,
            name = cryptoCoin.name,
            symbol = cryptoCoin.symbol,
            image = cryptoCoin.image,
            selected = cryptoCoin.selected
        )
    })
}
```

Now, if I delete the `coinDao.unselectAllCoins()` from the `updateSelectedCoin` method inside my repo, the test works ok

My question is, why since I'm running these access to the database in a blocking sequence inside a coroutine context failing my test?

I'm suspecting that the previous access before `coinDato.selectCoin(id)` is causing the issue, I have tried removing that and separating it into its own method with its own `coroutineContext`, but still the same thing.

What can I try next?

Incidentally, the error executing the test is in the line?

```
assertNotNull(selectedCoinId)
```

> java.lang.AssertionError

So it's saying that there is nothing in the db selected.

Comment: I don't know about the unit test behavior, but just want to point out that using `withContext` to call nothing but suspend functions is pointless. The DAO is using its own threads in its suspend function implementations. Since suspend functions must not block, it is never necessary to use a specific dispatcher to call them unless you are calling your own unconventionally defined (antipattern) blocking suspend function.

Comment: can you elaborate an answer for the question ? because in the Repository Pattern github repo from google, they do call suspend functions inside the Dispatcher.IO thread https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/blob/master/RepositoryPattern/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/devbyteviewer/repository/VideosRepository.kt

Comment: If the withContext is removed, the error is the same , I added the withContext to manage the thread where the tests are executed

Comment: Their example is wrong. They don’t need to use `withContext` there. It doesn’t hurt anything, and I wouldn’t expect it to cause problems. It’s just extra convolution that doesn’t accomplish anything except make readers of the code scratch their heads and wonder what they’re missing. They might wonder if one of those functions is blocking. Like if you do `if(someBoolean == true)` for a non-nullable Boolean, it will make people wonder if it’s nullable.

Comment: Can you provide a Solution for the answer rather than advices to the code ?

Comment: I don’t know Room unit testing. I was just suggesting something that might possibly be a factor. Usually when you unit test coroutines, things like delays are removed by the test dispatcher. But with Room and Retrofit, the suspend functions are not using dispatchers under the hood at all, and are basically ignoring the ones you try to run them with. They are using `suspendCancellableCoroutine` so the passed dispatcher is used only for setting up the asynchronous listener, but the asynchronous work is done in their own pools.

Comment: Not sure if that could be impacting how unit testing behaves. Feels like it shouldn’t, but I’m not well experienced with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and explanation into this, it helps undertand better the underlying